# Error in testing Generic Java Methods

Tags: java, generics, junit

I am following a tutorial on Generic methods in java and want to write a unit test for the method that involves generic type. But it is giving me the error **Ambiguous Method Call for assertEquals**

I tried to search for this error but no luck so far.I am posting my java and test classes below

**GenericMethods.java**

```
public class GenericMethods {

public <E> void printArray(E[] inputArray){
    //Display Array Elements
    List<E> values = Arrays.asList(inputArray);
    values.stream()
            .forEach(System.out::print);
}

public <T extends Comparable<T>> T returnMax(T x, T y, T z){
    T max = x; //Initially assume the firs element is max

    if(y.compareTo(max) > 0){
        max = y;
    }

    if(z.compareTo(max) > 0){
        max = z;
    }

    return max;
}
}
```

**GenericMethodsTest.java**

```
public class GenericMethodsTest {

GenericMethods genericMethods;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    genericMethods = new GenericMethods();
}

@Test
public <T> void shouldReturnCorrectMaximum() throws Exception {
     assertEquals(5,genericMethods.returnMax(3,4,5));

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because assertEquals takes both (Object, Object) and (long, long).  Try changing this to

```
assertEquals(new Integer(5), genericMethods.returnMax(3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason being

```
T returnMax(...) {..}
```

can return either of an `Object` or a `long` specifically for this case.

And [Assert class](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/) implementation has this method overloaded both for [long, long](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(long,%20long)) and [Object, Object](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) parameters. Hence using

```
assertEquals(5,genericMethods.returnMax(3,4,5));
```

would warn you of ambiguity between the two overloaded methods.

As suggested by @lane.maxwell, using `new Integer(5)` would instead make sure that the

```
static public void assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual)
```

is executed from the `Assert` class.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so nicely.